# 0x8024401c on all new WSUS clients

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, wsus

I keep getting the error 0x8024401c on all new clients connecting to WSUS. (Only Windows 10 and Server 2016)

According to Google, this error results to "WU_E_PT_HTTP_STATUS_REQUEST_TIMEOUT" but I can ping the server and access the /ClientWebService/client.asmx from the failing client.

Anyone got an idea how to fix this?

*Should I be worried about those 1601/01/01 Dates?*

```
...
2017/02/03 12:09:39.7930127 1868  8528  WebServices     WS error: There was an error communicating with the endpoint at 'http://wsus.fqdn:8530/ClientWebService/client.asmx'.
2017/02/03 12:09:39.7930135 1868  8528  WebServices     WS error: There was an error receiving the HTTP reply.
2017/02/03 12:09:39.7930143 1868  8528  WebServices     WS error: The operation did not complete within the time allotted.
2017/02/03 12:09:39.7930150 1868  8528  WebServices     WS error: The operation timed out
2017/02/03 12:09:39.7930162 1868  8528  WebServices     Web service call failed with hr = 8024401c.
2017/02/03 12:09:39.7930162 1868  8528  WebServices     Current service auth scheme=0.
2017/02/03 12:09:39.7930166 1868  8528  WebServices     Current Proxy auth scheme=0.
2017/02/03 12:09:41.7937260 1868  8528  WebServices     Auto proxy settings for this web service call.
1601/01/01 01:00:00.0000000 1868  8528                  Unknown( 49): GUID=2fc03aa6-a1fa-3d0c-ba09-b8539ec28a26 (No Format Information found).
1601/01/01 01:00:00.0000000 1868  8528                  Unknown( 57): GUID=2fc03aa6-a1fa-3d0c-ba09-b8539ec28a26 (No Format Information found).
1601/01/01 01:00:00.0000000 1868  8528                  Unknown( 11): GUID=2fc03aa6-a1fa-3d0c-ba09-b8539ec28a26 (No Format Information found).
...
```

**Edit:**

After almost a Month without google-success, it somehow works again. Maybe a Patch fixed it. If I find anything, I'll post here the results.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try running this on the problem-clients:

wuauclt /reportnow

wuauclt /detectnow

2. Make sure that patches did not alter any firewall settings.